# Connect to a postgres database in linux

Tags: postgresql

I am successfully login in with ssh to my linux server.

There I want to connect to my database

```
 psql myDatabase myuser
```

I am getting an error

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket 
    "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I am trying to trace if the postgres is running

```
ps auxwww | grep postgres
ec2-user 10117  0.0  0.1 110460  2068 pts/0    S+   21:43   0:00 grep --color=auto postgres
```

How can I connect to postgres ?

Comment: Well... **"Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket 
    "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?"* ? Like  the error says? Sounds like it's not running. So starting it would be a good plan. How did you install PostgreSQL?

Comment: is postgres installed? what do you see trying to start it with pg_ctl?..

Comment: The error message says the client could not found a socket of a locally running Postgres server. Your grep line also suggests there is no server running on this machine.